# Adjective position

Tags: adjectives, compound-adjectives, adjective-position

1.Mathematics teacher

2.Mathematic teacher

3.Teacher in mathematics

Which one is grammatically correct ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Mathematics teacher** is correct.  *Mathematics* here is a noun used attributively, not an adjective, and the correct term for this particular science is "[mathematics](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/mathematics)".

**Teacher of mathematics** would also be correct.

BrE uses the short form *maths*, e.g. **maths teacher**; AmE uses the short form *math*, e.g. **math teacher**.